# Core Bluetooth Background Processing

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth, core-bluetooth

[The app is a simple heart rate monitor from this link](http://www.raywenderlich.com/52080/introduction-core-bluetooth-building-heart-rate-monitor) and right now I'm just playing around with Core bluetooth and I'm trying to "perform long-term actions in the background" which involves  [Adding Support for State Preservation and Restoration](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/CoreBluetoothBackgroundProcessingForIOSApps/PerformingTasksWhileYourAppIsInTheBackground.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013257-CH7-SW7)

The first thing to do change the info.plist file then I "Opt In to State Preservation and Restoration" by replacing

```
CBCentralManager *centralManager = [[CBCentralManager alloc] initWithDelegate:self queue:nil];
```

in my MainviewController.m with

```
CBCentralManager *centralManager = [[CBCentralManager alloc] initWithDelegate:self queue:nil options:@{CBCentralManagerOptionRestoreIdentifierKey:@"myCentralManager"}];
```

The second step involves "Reinstantiate any central or peripheral manager objects after your app is relaunched by the system".

I do this by adding

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions{

    self.centralManager = [[CBCentralManager alloc] initWithDelegate:self queue:nil options:@{CBCentralManagerOptionRestoreIdentifierKey:@“myCentralManager”}];
    return YES;
}
```

Next step is to "Implement the Appropriate Restoration Delegate Method"

```
-(void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central willRestoreState:(NSDictionary *)dict {
    NSLog(@"willRestoreState called");
    self.myPeripheral = [dict[CBCentralManagerRestoredStatePeripheralsKey] firstItem];
    self.myPeripheral.delegate = self;
}
```

Are these the right steps? Is there anything I am missing out? (I can't seem to find any information about doing this)

Comment: You've reinstantiated the CentralManager with the AppDelegate as the delegate instead of MainviewController in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions. Besides that, you've not said what the problem is..

Comment: @Marcus Adams ok this is probably a stupid question but how do you do this? (When i've been using delegates most of the time its to self.) Is it making a ATprotocol and a ATproperty delegate in the MainViewController?